# Show $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a^n+b^n)^{\frac 1n}=\max \{a,b\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Need help proving $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a^n+b^n)^{\frac 1n}=\max \{a,b\}$. We have tried using binomial theorem but have very few ideas. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $b$ is the larger of the two, then $b^n\le a^n+b^n\le 2b^n$.

Comment: @DavidMitra - what if $a<0$ and $n$ is odd. Then $b^n \geq a^n + b^n$.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that a and b were positive. Thank you for the help

Comment: Then @DavidMitra's comment is 100% correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $a\ge b$:
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a^n+b^n)^{\frac 1n}=a\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\left(\frac ba\right)^n\right)^{\frac 1n}=a,$$
as you take the $n^{th}$ root of a term between $1$ and $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this identity is known as *Maslov's dequantization*.

Here $a$ and $b$ are non-negative so we have $a^n + b^n \geq \max(a^n, b^n) = \max(a, b)^n$, hence $\liminf_n (a^n + b^n)^{1/n} \geq \max(a, b)$.

To prove the complete identity, suppose for instance that $b > a$. 
Then $(a^n + b^n)^{1/n} = \exp(\frac{1}{n} \log(a^n + b^n)) = b \exp(\frac{1}{n} \log(1 + (a/b)^n))$, and now it is easy to conclude since $\log(1 + (a/b)^n) \sim (a/b)^n$.